# How to combine two chip enable(/CE) signals into one with discrete components?

Tags: transistors, diodes, logic-gates, rom

My VIC-20 has a few bank select lines that are used for enabling ROM chips on the cartridge port.  When one of them goes low, it means that a certain 8KB region of the address space has been accessed.

Usually you can hook these up directly to the chip enable (/CE) pin of a ROM chip to essentially place that 8KB ROM into a certain slot in memory.

However, I have a 16KB ROM with only one /CE pin which means that I need to combine two bank select lines.  I know I can do this with a single AND gate (since the logic is inverted), but it seems like a waste to use a quad-AND or NAND chip if there was a simpler solution.

Note, only one of the bank select lines ever goes low at a time.  So the truth table would be kind of like:

```
A|B|O
-----
1|1|1
0|1|0
1|0|0
0|0|Never happens
```

Is there an elegant way to do this with discrete components?

Comment: Use diodes and a resistor. .

Comment: I'm not sure what that would look like...

Comment: If you google diode and gate you'll see. This answer should be fleshed out.

Comment: Have you seen Little Logic yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No, I hadn't!  Thanks for the info.

Comment: VIC20! Ha. Haha. Hahaha. WOW !!!. Congratulations! I have a few lurking somewhere in the deep dungeon. Must be getting near time to dig them out again :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diode-OR them:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVh3UE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Either input can pull the output low, and only the pullup will pull it high.

Comment: 1N4148 or similar small-signal diodes of course, not 1N4007's. :)

Comment: And I suppose a 10K pullup for a 5v supply?

Comment: 10K is reasonable -- what's the current sinking capability of the driver? I can almost guarantee 10K is fine, but if you want to dot your i's and cross your t's, that's the thing to check.

Comment: @SamWashburn: It depends on how quickly you need the signal to rise and how much current the diodes and memory controller output can handle.

Comment: @KrunalDesai The drivers are 74LS138 for the chip select lines.

Comment: Looks like it is specified at 4 and 8mA -- definitely overthinking it, but figured it was worth it as a learning exercise. You're good with 10k unless I'm missing something exotic.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The system clock is a little more than 1MHz.

Comment: Wouldn't Shottky diodes be a better choice than ordinary silicon diodes if we mind the driver output voltage levels @ logical low?